# Google Drive indexableText for a video in Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api, metadata

I am trying to add [indexable text](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/file) to a video already in drive. From the [Drive SDK Docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/patch) I used the Patch method.

```
def add_indexable_text(service, file_id, text_to_index):
  try:
    file = {'indexableText': {'text': text_to_index}}
    updated_file = service.files().patch(
      fileId = file_id,
      body = file,
      fields = 'indexableText').execute()

    return updated_file
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
    return None
```

I'm not seeing any errors in the terminal but when I search in drive for the metadata text there are no results. I've tried waiting for a while but that didn't seem to help/matter. The video says it was updated when I ran the script so there's something. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Update: It seems I can only add indexableText to a video once but not change it afterward.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine to me. Try using the "try it" function of the docs, does that work?

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/patch

Maybe the request went through but failed, which causes no HttpError.

What's the return value from a typical call?

Comment: Yes tried patch and [update](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update) as well and they each return a 200, the video shows that has been modified recently but the search still fails. Without a get method I'm not sure how else to debug it, the response does not include the indexableText because it is not returned by the get (see [file reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files))

Comment: If you sent the request through the docs page, and it doesn't work, its probably Google's problem. I tried patching a file, giving it indexableText then taking it away, adding the text worked, but removing it using update or patch both had no effect.

Comment: Hmm I tried it with a different id and it worked, but when I tried to do it again it won't update/change the indexed text. Is it only possible to add indexed text once?

Comment: Updating failed for me too, I suppose it takes sometime before the effect will take place? It's clearly Google's problem